# R: How to automate calculating a data frame then producing a chart based on the results for multiple data frames?

Tags: python, r, oop, dynamic, repeat

How can I build a dynamic "downflow pipeline" to push data frames through with R to auto-calculate formulas using these data frames? I have this data frame called autocalc, which has blank spaces carved out for equations. For example, I need to apply equations such as this:  `autocalc$PPH <- Tokyo$P / Tokyo$PH` .  PPH is already a column/vector.

```
autocalc <- data.frame("INCOME" = c("$0 to $15,000","$15,000 to $29,999","$30,000 to $39,999","$40,000 to $49,999","$50,000 to $69,999","$70,000 to $99,999","$100,000 to $149,999"),
                             "PPH" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                             "PTS" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
    
    autocalc$PPH <- Tokyo$P / Tokyo$PH 
    autocalc$PTS <- autocalc$PPH * .05
```

The results of this data frame will be used to build a chart with ggplot2.

As you can see from the sample equation, there is a data frame called Tokyo. I have three city data frames (NewYork, Paris, Tokyo). Each data frame has the city's prisoners (vector P) and population (vector PH). The data is further categorized by income group.

```
Tokyo <- data.frame("INCOME" = c("$0 to $15,000","$15,000 to $29,999","$30,000 to $39,999","$40,000 to $49,999","$50,000 to $69,999","$70,000 to $99,999","$100,000 to $149,999"),
                          "P" = c(1844,1062,1036,448,770,364,395),
                          "PH" = c(84900,721007,80800,380004,675000,32900,39500))
```

I want to apply each city to the autocalc data frame and produce three separate charts. I could copy/paste three versions of autocalc for each city, but that seems like bad code because if I have to fix something in autocalc, I have to redo the code for each city.

I looked at the following leads, but I feel like this shouldn't be that complex of an issue:

1. Use objective oriented programming with the R6 library. Create an autocalc class and apply a copy to the three cities? There aren't many R6 tutorials that make sense for a beginner, so I feel like there's an easier way?
2. Use lapply(). I found a tutorial that produces something similar (three separate charts based on three separate data frames), but it can't explain how to swap `autocalc$PPH <- Tokyo$P / Tokyo$PH` for `autocalc$PPH <- Paris$P / Paris$PH` . And to preserve autocalc's calculations with each city, to prepare three charts.  Should I instead get rid of the autocalc data frame and add rows to each city's data frame?
3. My friend not well versed in R, but is a programmer, and recommends looking into collection methods. To write a script and use methods to do repeated operations. However, I can't find a tutorial to do with R. I think this requires me to use object-oriented programming with the R6 library? I'm thinking maybe my task is better suited with Python then? I'm being told that R is more for analysis and not building something as dynamic as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think option 2 is the most easy and straight-forward one. You can put the 3 dataframes in a list and use `lapply`. You can pass an anonymous function in `lapply` to refer to the each cities dataframe inside the function.

```
list_dfs <- list(Tokyo, Paris, NewYork)

list_plots <- lapply(list_dfs, function(x) {
  autocalc$PPH <- x$P / x$PH 
  autocalc$PTS <- autocalc$PPH * .05
  #ggplot2  code here
})
```

After you enter the `ggplot2` code in `lapply`, it will generate a list of 3 plots for each city which you can access by doing `list_plots[[1]]`, `list_plots[[2]]` and `list_plots[[3]]`.

Comment: Thank you this is definitely a step in the right direction. But, I'm getting this error when running the code: `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` . I tried swapping x$P and x$PH with    `x[["P"]]` and `x[,"P"]`. However I get new errors about subscript being outside of bounds.

Comment: @AvocadoBoat Are you sure your columns are named as `P` and `PH` in the dataframe `Tokyo`, `Paris` etc. Did you run the first line `list_dfs <- list(Tokyo, Paris, NewYork)` ?

Comment: Yes, they are named correctly and I ran the first line. However, when I test printed list_dfs, only the words Tokyo, Paris, NewYork showed up. The entire data frame for each city did not print. So I do not think the data frames were put into the list. Just the name of the data frames. This might explain the atomic vector error and the subscript outside of bounds error. But I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: So you only have names in those cities. What are those 3 dataframes for each city called? Are you adding quotes to the names like this?  `list_dfs <- list('Tokyo', 'Paris', 'NewYork')`. We don't need quotes there, see my answer `list_dfs <- list(Tokyo, Paris, NewYork)` It is without quotes.

Comment: That was my bad. Removing the quotation marks solved it! Thank you. Unfortunately, now the three plots are identical.  I took out the ggplot2 code and tried to produce `list_plots` as tables by running `list_plots[[1]] list_plots[[2]]  list_plots[[3]]` after the lapply code, and they are all the same of the first city on the list_dfs.

Comment: @AvocadoBoat Can you edit your post to include output of `dput(lapply(list_dfs, head))` to your post?

Comment: I am an idiot and forgot to change the data within the city data frames, so they were all using Tokyo's data. After changing the data within each city data frame, everything is coming out correctly. Everything works now! Thank you for your patience Ronak!